# Is there no need to store Hashed password, if I use PBKDF2 or RFC2898 code encrypt or decrypt data in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

Actual referenced code is appended in the end.
From what I can understand from the [code for **PBKDF2** or **RFC2898** in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netcore-3.1)  as given in the above link .

I have come to the following conclusion. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Storing of Password

> **pwd1**

is **not** **necessary**.

2. Storing of Salt     **

> **salt1**

** is     **necessary**.

3. If password is hashed to form key '**k1**', to encrypt the '**data1**'  to '**edata1**' , even storing the hashed password = key

> **k1**

, is ****not** **necessary****. The reason behind my thinking is encrypted data ‘**edata1**’ can only be decrypted with key ‘**k1**’ and ‘**k1**’ can only be generated if the user enters the right password ‘**pwd1**’.

Conclusion : Password ‘**pwd1**’   need not be stored.
Neither hashed password i.e. , ‘**k1**’ needs to be stored.
Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class rfc2898test
{
    // Generate a key k1 with password pwd1 and salt salt1.
    // Generate a key k2 with password pwd1 and salt salt1.
    // Encrypt data1 with key k1 using symmetric encryption, creating edata1.
    // Decrypt edata1 with key k2 using symmetric decryption, creating data2.
    // data2 should equal data1.

    private const string usageText = "Usage: RFC2898 <password>\nYou must specify the password for encryption.\n";
    public static void Main(string[] passwordargs)
    {
        //If no file name is specified, write usage text.
        if (passwordargs.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(usageText);
        }
        else
        {
            string pwd1 = passwordargs[0];
            // Create a byte array to hold the random value.
            byte[] salt1 = new byte[8];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new
RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Fill the array with a random value.
                rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1);
            }

            //data1 can be a string or contents of a file.
            string data1 = "Some test data";
            //The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the same iteration count.
            int myIterations = 1000;
            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1,
myIterations);
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
                // Encrypt the data.
                Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
                encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
                MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream,
encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(
data1);

                encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
                encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypt.Close();
                byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
                k1.Reset();

                // Try to decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped.
                Aes decAlg = Aes.Create();
                decAlg.Key = k2.GetBytes(16);
                decAlg.IV = encAlg.IV;
                MemoryStream decryptionStreamBacking = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(
decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);
                decrypt.Flush();
                decrypt.Close();
                k2.Reset();
                string data2 = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(
decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());

                if (!data1.Equals(data2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: The two values are not equal.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The two values are equal.");
                    Console.WriteLine("k1 iterations: {0}", k1.IterationCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("k2 iterations: {0}", k2.IterationCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually you use a password derivation function (like PBKDF2) to get a key (here "k1") to encrypt **and** decrypt, so for decryption the user enters the password again and through the PBKDF2 you receive the (same) key again for decryption. It would be **unsafe** to store the key ("k1") anywhere. Just one thing to keep in mind - you need to store the (randomly) generated salt AND the number of iterations to rebuild the same key.

Comment: This example code is strange. If it runs without error, then it demonstrates that `new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1, 1000);` and `new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);` are equal. It means that not specifying the iteration count leads to an iteration count of 1000. It could have been done easier like actually putting this default behavior into the documentation. -.-

Comment: @ArtjomB it is "hidden" in a comment in the sample code of the documentation: `//The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the same iteration count.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1